# MacOS Photos seems to import two copies of each picture

Tags: photos

Not every single picture, but it seems the majority of pictures that I imported into MacOS Photos have a duplicate. I am not sure why. Is it some interaction with Photo Streams? Does it have to do with having both a RAW and Jpeg? Is it a bug? Have you seen this?

Comment: Have you taken the said pictures in HDR mode? It's possible that the duplicate photo is the normal mode copy of the photo taken in HDR mode.